# Function populates first listbox but not the second from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, html

Function `popList()` takes two parameters - name of the column and name of the table.
Basically the `popList(`) function connects to a `mysql` server and then a database and builds an sql query to retrieve data based on what you passed to the function to be used to populate a listbox on the page.

Only one listbox works fine with the function, but if there's a second listbox on the page that calls the function again with different parameters(column name and table name) passed it appears empty and the following is printed in the source of the page right under the source of the first populated listbox:

> **Warning**:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access
>   denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\test** on line **7**
>  Not connected :
>   Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I use the same connection credentials in both calls which are default localhost, root and no password(purely for testing purposes)

Why is it behaving like this?

**EDIT***(source)*:

```
<?php
function popList($col, $tbl) {

    require_once "credentials.php";

    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
      die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
      die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT $field FROM $table";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row["$field"] . '">' . $row["$field"] . '</option>';
    }

    mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

**SOLUTION**:

*NEW*: Seems like using `require_once` and `include_once` causes the issue, but using `include` or `require` actually fixes the problem.

<strike>Replaced `require_once "credentials.php"` with the actual code from `credentials.php` like so</strike>:

```
function popList(...) {

require "credentials.php"; // changed to require from require_once. same with include


...
}
```

Comment: We might need to see the code...

Comment: It would very much appear as though `$username` is being changed between function calls; perhaps search the rest of your code for references to that variable?

Comment: There's no way. credentials.php has only root for username and that function uses it in both cases. Why would it change root to ODBC after the first call? Maybe I'm already connected when calling the function second time?

Comment: I'd nevertheless search for every reference to `$username`, in your PHP script and all included files, to see which lines are capable of changing its value.  Then backtrack to see if any of those lines might be being executed.  On the other hand, you could always force `$username = "root";` just before your second call to the `popList()` function - but without getting to the bottom of how it got changed, you might end up breaking something else in the process.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I guess it has something to do with `require_once` part of the function definition. I just pasted the connection credentials from `credentials.php` right into the top part of function and it works now. Both listboxes get populated. Perhaps the `require once "credentials.php"` caused such behavior. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once` does what it says: it requires **once**.  The first time `popList` is called, everything in `credentials.php` gets dumped into your function's scope.  The second time `popList` is called, *nothing happens* because `credentials.php` was already required once during this run.

You should have a configuration object somewhere rather than a pile of variables in a file, you should never use `require` or `include` within a function like that, and you should have `E_STRICT` turned on so you'll see the warnings about `$password` etc not being defined.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting you,

> I use the same connection credentials in both calls which are default localhost, root and no password(purely for testing purposes)

Since you're mentioning root user with no password, and in the error, it comes as: **`Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`** which means you're actually trying to connect user `ODBC` with no password, which I think is having a password.

Comment: @Bob The second attempt to connect is attempting to connect as "ODBC".

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do like this

```
$query="SELECT * FROM bus_type order by bus_type_id Asc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo "<select name=bustype size=sizes class=bus_txtbox value=''>Type of the Bus</option>";
    while($line=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=$line[bus_type_id]>$line[bus_type]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```